# Mold got painted over. Now regrowing through the paint. What next?

Tags: bathroom, mold, humidity

The property manager sent out a handyperson, who spent about 10 minutes on shower mold, basically just painting over it.  Now several months later the mold is showing through again.

What can be done at this point?

[image: Mold under paint bathroom humidity]

Update:
There was a roof leak nearby, but likely this started as surface mold from the showers.  There is a window, but no manual exhaust fan or humidity sensor fan.

The wall and ceiling are uninsulated.  The climate is Zone 3 (Marine) (Mild, temperature ranges 40-70F year round, relatively humidity is always high at 50-80% outdoors).

The windows are left open during showering.

The QUESTION is aimed at the methods needed to get the ceiling properly remediated.

Comment: some recommend to use bleach to kill it

Comment: Tell the manager to do it right this time or get the health department involved and they make him do it right.

Comment: Mold grew there in the 1st pace because the environmental conditions were right for it. Has that issue been addressed? Is there proper venting in place to ensure that warm moist air doesn't hang around there for long? Your property manager could have sent the best mold remediation experts in the state over to clean up the mold, but if the cause doesn't get addressed it'll just come back again and again. So - is there an extractor fan (and do you use it)? Do you ever open that window?

Comment: It's the tenant responsibility to clean up mold, and also to vent the bathroom **as needed to control humidity** so mold doesn't happen in the first place.  This is 100% tenant responsibility and they need to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is the cold wall, but your property manager would not add a good insulation to this building.
There will be mould at the grey wall surface too, but you do not see it because of the colour.

Two options:

1. You can install a humidity measurement device to see the humidity values, if this value is to high, then a ventilator should start to exchange the air for a minute.
2. Or you do it manually and open the window every time after the showering for a while. The problem is the water what is left in the shower, this will evaporate during the time and increase the humidity after a while over a critical point too, so that you have to ventilate again.

To fix it:
Use a thermal camera and take a look at the cold areas, if only the ceiling is cold, then you can insulate the ceiling with Styrodur (from BASF) or similar material. Seal the gaps with acrylic.
But you need a under-costruction and then some panels to cover the area.

Comment: The wall is tile, so would not show mold.
The windows are opened during showering.

Comment: @ScottBrown - Mold can grow everywhere, even on a plastic surface, it only need some moisture. Use a spong and rub it over the gray surface very close to the ceiling.

Comment: If you look carefully you can see mold in the grout.